# Using <xs:appinfo> to specify version information

Tags: xsd, annotations

I have found few examples of "standard" usage of `<xs:appinfo>`.  This one is interesting: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/schema/ch15_01.htm#ch15-77057, however I would like to provide info like "used since v1.3" or "deprecated since v1.1".  Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Both `<xs:documentation>` and `<xs:appinfo>` allow as children any other XML elements without limitations (along with just text).

The XSD language does not specify what exactly that extra XML and its meaning might be.
It purpose is just to allow for anyone to extend particular schema/components with 
some extra (structured) information, which could be processed/used further automatically.

So, it is completely up to you how to design that extra XML (which would extend your documentation) and how to process and use it.

For that matter, one usage of such extra XML is to format the annotation text with **HTML**. In that case, that custom XML will be simply **XHTML**.

Comment: Yes, I know it is not specified: I was searching for commonly used solutions.